function at bootstrap 4 carousel image slide event
I am using bootstrap 4 carousel with 11 slides which are working fine as desired. I have another div (#div-info) say in which I wish to display certain Text and some other image as per carousel slide. I mean when slide no. 2 is
active, it must display text as SLIDE 2 and some fix images as per slide 2 in another div (#div-info) and when carousel moves to next slide i.e. 3, the another specific text and specific images is to display in div(#div-info).
I had observed the event "slide.bs.carousel" but unable to find the solution.
Please help. I am very much novice in JavaScript and jQuery but I would try me level best to follow your
instructions.

The slide.bs.carousel event is exactly what you need to use. The Bootstrap documentation has a reference and examples showing its use. What part in particular are you having an issue with? I would suggest you add your code to the question so that we can help you to debug it.

You should have at least provided some code example. Your question is not clear

In Bootstrap 4 there is a class carousel-caption under this class you can place your text and images. And for further modification, you need to style the image and font with CSS. Here is example code from Bootstrap 4 document
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="img01.png" alt="First slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>First Slide</h5>
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img02.png" alt="First slide" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="img02.png" alt="Second slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Second Slide</h5>
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img03.png" alt="Second slide" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="img03.png" alt="Third slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Third Slide</h5>
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img01.png" alt="Third slide" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>


Thanks for your reply sir. Let me try as per your suggestion. Will revert back.

Try slid.bs.carousel.
From their docs:
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (ev) {
  // do somethig with 
  console.log(ev.from, ev.to)
})


Thanks for your response. Although I am bit novice in java script, but will try to follow your pints.
